# Error when using Glide

Tags: android

The app crashes when I try to load an image with *Glide*.

I have the following code:

.java:

```
ImageButton home_ib1;

Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_24_hours_to_live)
            .override(98, 155)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.moviep_24_hours_to_live)
            .into(home_ib1);
```

.xml:

```
<ScrollView
   <RelativeLayout


<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib1"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And when I try to run  app, i got crash..(LogCat: You must pass in a non null View)
(The image's resolution that i have to load is 175x276 PNG)

Comment: Share your java code completely?Your passing null value.Did u initialized `imageView``

Comment: where do you initialize home_ib1? this view is null

Comment: provide us with the full java code, and the full error text description from Logcat to help you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageButton home_ib1;`

Looks Like home_ib1 is null

Just add

`home_ib1 = findViewById(R.id.home_ib1);`

Comment: what do you mean? How can I change it to not be null?

Comment: Just add

home_ib1 = findViewById(R.id.home_ib1);